# Suppressing TikZ errors about calculations

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, plot, silence

I'm trying to plot the graph of a curve as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$y$};
    
    \draw[thick, domain=-2.2:-1, smooth, variable=\y, blue] plot [samples=500]  ({pow(\y*\y -1, (1/3))},{\y});
    \draw[thick, domain=-1:1, smooth, variable=\y, blue] plot [samples=1000] ({-pow(1-\y*\y, (1/3))},{\y});
    \draw[thick, domain=1:2.2, smooth, variable=\y, blue] plot [samples=500] ({pow(\y*\y -1, (1/3))},{\y});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives me the picture
[image: a graph that does not look perfect]
I'm trying to close the visible gap by intentionally going out of boundaries slightly, by writing

```
    \draw[thick, domain=-2.2:-0.99, smooth, variable=\y, blue] plot [samples=500]  ({pow(\y*\y -1, (1/3))},{\y});
    \draw[thick, domain=-1:1.01, smooth, variable=\y, blue] plot [samples=1000] ({-pow(1-\y*\y, (1/3))},{\y});
    \draw[thick, domain=1:2.2, smooth, variable=\y, blue] plot [samples=500] ({pow(\y*\y -1, (1/3))},{\y});
```

which gives a visually satisfactory graph, but understandably causes some PGF Math errors complaining that I'm trying to calculate the logarithms of negative numbers in a few (superfluous) cases. I want to suppress these errors using the `silence` package as they don't do real harm. However, `\ErrorsOff[tikz,pgf,pgfplots]` fails to turn off the errors. Any answer letting me know how to turn of the errors or suggesting a more elegant way to plot the curve is very appreciated.

Comment: Please post a MNWE we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the error.

Comment: Pretty sure this is basically a TeX error and not in `silence`'s purview.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the suggestion. I supplied the basic document commands. The only changes the second code snippet brings by are changes to the numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a function that avoids taking the third root of a negative number. In your case, you need `-sign(1-\y*\y)*pow(abs(1-\y*\y),1/3)`. This function can be plotted in the complete domain.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={f(\y)=-sign(1-\y*\y)*pow(abs(1-\y*\y),1/3);}]
    \draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$y$};    
    \draw[thick, domain=-2.2:2.2, smooth, variable=\y, blue] 
    plot [samples=101]  ({f(\y)},{\y});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]